# eclipse 2023-03 (4.27.0) Windows 10 ssh push to github always fail

Tags: git, eclipse, ssh, key

This is the error I get in Eclipse.

[image: error]

I try to set up git in eclipse to push via SSH.

- I created a private key in eclipse and registered the public one on GitHub as an access key.
- I assigned the ssh key in eclipse for SSH connections
- I set up the origin for my project with the ssh url

But when I then want to the ssh connectivity to git, I get the following log and error:

```
prompt>ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\cschl/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-a5657383
debug1: no match: babeld-a5657383
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ******************** 
SHA256:********************************
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
Host key verification failed.
```

Similar when I push out of eclipse. The key is always invalid.

Totally stuck. Spent the last two days trying to fix this, but no success.
any help highly welcome

I describe what I did further up

Comment: additional info:
the key was created with pass phrase and during the push operation in eclipse I'm requested to enter it which I do.

Answer (score 1):

The SSH URL is incorrect, as it uses a `username@github.com`, instead of `git@github.com`.

You should always use the service account git, when connecting to a remote Git repository hosting service (like GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, ...): the remote service will know who you are based on the public key you would have [first added to your account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

Change the remote URL in the Eclipse repository view and try again to push.

Comment: I tried that before as you can see from the log output. 
I just tried it again with git@ and it connected successfully but I've no idea why this is working now. 
still the main issue is to get ecplipse to successfully push to git via SSH.
I still get the error that I posted as image in the OP

Comment: ok, I didn't change username to git in the origin push url ... I could successfully push now but the cimmitted changes do not show up in the remote repo.
anyways, this was already a great help, thanks heaps :)

Comment: @ranxero Well done. Did you find out why your changes are not shown in the remote repository? Did you commit those changes? In the main branch?

Comment: yes, due to my lack of experience with git I pushed into a new branch :) 
all good now ... thanks heaps!

Comment: @ranxero perfect, again well done.